# Create HTML header and footer for wrapping third party content in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create an HTML header and footer file from my WordPress php. I need to provide these files for a third-party that builds the page for me. the basic layout is:

header.html
their content
footer.html

how can i dynamically create the header.html and footer.html?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question, you can use php includes for the header and footer.

Comment: I have to provide HTML files to Sportsnetwork for them to put their feed in between. I want to use the header and footer php files that are already in my theme, but I don't know how to generate an html version of those files.

Comment: Probably a better approach would be for them to give you their code, and then you stick it in your header or footer template and then adjust it until it shows how you want it to.

Comment: I totally agree, but they won't do that...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't think you are going to change your theme any time soon, just save the source of one of the pages and then cut and paste.

Alternatively you could browse to whatever include file your template stores the header in and then do a view source save as header.html and likewise for the footer.

user JQuery to load the inc file into the body of the html page

```
<html>
   <script src="path/to/jquery">...
    ...
   <body>
         loading include
   </body>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('body').load('path/to/include.php', function() {
          /// do nothing
        });
      });
  </script>
</html>
```

or even better still, I assume they will give you a page that has your header, their crap, your footer.  If thats true

header...

```
<html>
 ...
 <body>
    <div id="their-crap">
```

footer...

```
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and then where ever you want to put that data, do

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('selector-you-want').load('path/to/renderedpage#their-crap', function() {
          /// do nothing
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but we have content in a couple of places that changes daily.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll add some ideas using jquery to load the rendered php into the html or go the opposite direction and load the data they spit out into a div or whatever you wanted